# Finding the average revenue per day for multiple projects

Tags: mean

I want to measure the value of a client based on the average project fee and average length of the project in days. We combined the two to create a Revenue/Day metric - it's inelegant but works well enough for our purposes.

I want to determine the Average Revenue/Day for all projects with a specific client, but I am unsure about the best way to calculate.

Say we conducted 3 projects with a client

Project 1: Fee = 100,000 | Length = 100 days | Revenue/Day = 1,000

Project 2: Fee = 120,000 | Length = 90 days | Revenue/Day = 1,333

Project 3: Fee = 135,000 | Length = 75 days | Revenue/Day = 1,800

If we handle each discretely, and take the average of the revenue/day totals, it equals $1,378.

However, if you take the total fees and divide by total days, you get $1,340. This to me seems like the average of averages, so I think it's incorrect.

I think $1,378$ is the correct number, with the equation being something like:
$$
\left(\frac{\text{fee}}{\text{day}}+\frac{\text{fee}}{\text{day}}+\frac{\text{fee}}{\text{day}}\right) / n = x
$$
with $x=\text{average revenue/day}$.

Is that right?

Comment: isn't there any cost associated with a client? how is the cost not in the value? you can have a needy client who would generate a lot of revenue but at a very high cost

Answer (score 2):

The correct average revenue must be total revenue / total days, with your numbers this becomes
$$
    \frac{100000+120000+135000}{100+90+75}
$$
You can express this as an weighted average by reexpressing the fraction above as
$$
  \frac{100}{265}\frac{100000}{100}+\frac{90}{265}\frac{120000}{90}+\frac{75}{265}\frac{135000}{75}
$$
which shows that the right weighted average have weight "the fraction of days worked" and data the revenue per day for each project.